# decorate python-telegram-bot async function with threading wrapper exception

Tags: multithreading, async-await, wrapper, python-telegram-bot

python-telegram-bot document:
Since v20.0, python-telegram-bot is built on top of Pythons asyncio module. Because asyncio is in general single-threaded, python-telegram-bot does currently not aim to be thread-safe.

If bot command execute some long time work,will block the whole BOT recieve and send message.So I want use wrapper to thead bot command task.
The follow is my code. test command can normal execure.
But I get exception object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression.
So somewhere should be have worng.

```
def asyncbot(mythread):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):  
        def wrap_async_func(*args, **kwargs):
            asyncio.run(mythread(*args, **kwargs))
        _thread = Thread(target=wrap_async_func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        _thread.start()
    return wrapper

@asyncbot
async def test(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    sleep(20)
```

> logging:

An exception was raised while handling an update update =

> "None"

```
    context.chat_data = None
    
    context.user_data = None

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/telegram/ext/_jobqueue.py", line 898, in _run
    await self.callback(context)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your decorator does not return a coroutine function. PTB expects that all callback function are corutine functions (`async def`) that can be `await`-ed, so your handler must return such a function.

However, I do want to point out that starting a thread seems not to be the bestion solution. Alternatives to consider:

- using asyncio-friendly code (in your case `asycnio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep`)
- using tools from the std-lib like [`loop.run_in_excutor`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=run_in_executor#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)
- using ptbs included [concurrency utilities](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Concurrency)

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.